# Need help understanding why my s3 bucket always has 4xx errors?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch

So I'm montioring and s3 bucket that is accessed through an SFTP server on AWS. I'm monitoring the 4xx error request metric and have set up an alarm to sum up all 4xx errors in a 24 hour period and check if its below 20. The issue I'm having is it seems that even when the s3 bucket isn't being used I have a couple of 4xx errors on a daily basis. And I'm not sure why. If anyone has any idea why this might be any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: did you manage to find out how to see the URI for the 4XX errors? I can't figure that out as well.